# Remove sub-string from URL containing only numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a few URL's like these

- https://{Domain}/rent/abcdef/2019/Canada
- https:/{Domain}/buy/Supported/2019/Gill-Avenue

I want to remove '2019'or any part which contain only numbers from these Url's so that the Url's look as below

- https://{Domain}/rent/abcdef/Canada
- https:/{Domain}/buy/Supported/Gill-Avenue

How can i achieve this using javascript

Comment: You don't want jQuery for this as it's primarily a framework for manipulating the DOM. You want JS, and specifically Regular Expressions.

Comment: here's a regular expression tutorial: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this;

```
let str = "https://test.com/rent/abcdef/2019/Canada";
str.replace(/\/\d+/g, '');
```

Comment: Consider adding the global flag to support cases where a URL has more than one set of numbers `/\/\d+/g`.

Comment: It is required if the text contains more than number part. thanks @Grafluxe

Comment: Almost. You have to define a variable to `str.replace()`, or change `str` to its replacement. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that: 
split on `'/'`, filter with a /d regex and rejoin with `'/'`

I can't try right now sorry

```
window.location.href.split('/').filter(substr => !(/^\d+$/.match(substr))).join('/')
```

Comment: You can simply use the `replace` function to solve this problem without having to call 4 separate functions. It would be faster, cleaner, and more simple to understand.

Comment: "I can't try right now sorry" What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this for the first:

```
var str = "https://example.com/rent/abcdef/2019/Canada"
str = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
str = str.replace("f//", "f/");
```

And for the second:

```
var str = "https://example.com/rent/abcdef/2019/Canada"
str = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
str = str.replace("d//", "d/");
```

So this is if you want to replace just 1 digit. The first one  of each of these works but adds a new `/` backslash to the whole link after the last letter before the `/` in the old version. To remove that, you do the second, which contains the last letter to not remove the `://` too. The way is to find the last letter of each of these numbers before the backslash after using the first `replace()` function and replace them to remove the extra backslash.

This might work for easy things, like if you already know the URL, but for complicated things like a very big project, this is no easy way to do it. If you want "easy", then check other answers.

As said, you can also do this:

```
let str = "https://test.com/rent/abcdef/2019/Canada";
var withNoNum = str.replace(/\/\d+/g, '');
```

This is going to remove groups of numbers. So I added a new string `withNoNum` which is `str`'s replacement with no numbers, which might be more good because if you are doing a website that allows you to send your own website and remove the numbers from it to get a new site.

This also might help you with this problem: [removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993764/removing-numbers-from-string)